# How to make systemd services run automatically after reboot?

Tags: systemd

I'm desperate. I'm making a camera project with a Raspberry Pi, I'm running `Raspbian Buster` there, and for the love of God, I cannot make my scripts run after reboot by using `systemd`. I can start them just fine, but they will be always `inactive (dead)` after the reboot.

My units are in the `/home/pi/.config/systemd/user/` . And they are:

`camera-control.service`

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Description=Camera position controlling server

[Service]
ExecStart=python3 "${HOME}/scripts/start.camera_control.server.py"
```

And:

`camera-stream.service`

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Description=Camera streaming

[Service]
ExecStart=bash "${HOME}/scripts/start.stream.sh"
```

The python script basically is running the TCPServer with `server.serve_forever()`, and bash script is this:

```
mkdir -p "${HOME}/storage"

raspivid --nopreview -ih -hf -vf --width 800 --height 600 --framerate 15 --bitrate 2000000 --profile main --timeout 0 -g 4 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc do-timestamp=true ! h264parse ! tee name=t \
 t. ! queue ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=dom.zaroda.pl port=8004 \
 t. ! queue ! splitmuxsink location="${HOME}/storage/%02d.mkv" max-size-time=30000000000 muxer=matroskamux
```

Both services correctly run with `systemctl --user start camera-control`. But they never, ever will run after the reboot.

Now I tried A LOT of things. With every change I'm doing `systemctl --user daemon-reload` and I'm re-enabling them - I'm making sure that they are always enabled.

- I tried to add `exec` before the `raspivid`.
- I tried to add

this:

```
After=network-online.target
```

To the `Unit` section.

and this:

```
After=network.target
```

and this:

```
Before=network-online.target
```

And this:

```
Wants=network-online.target
```

In every configuration I could find on the internet.

I also tried all of this with setting the type of service to: `forking` and `oneshot`.

I enabled `systemd-networkd` service and added to the `Unit` section things like:

```
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Requires=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

All of the above in countless configurations. It just won't work. Everytime I will reboot with these two services enabled, I'm getting the same states with `systemctl --user status camera-stream` and `systemctl --user status camera-control` :

```
● camera-stream.service - Camera streaming
   Loaded: loaded (/home/pi/.config/systemd/user/camera-stream.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

● camera-control.service - Camera position controlling server
   Loaded: loaded (/home/pi/.config/systemd/user/camera-control.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

There is nothing in `journalctl`.

I must be missing something embarrassingly simple. Do you have any suggestions what else I can try to make it work? I feel like I brute forced every configuration of the above mentioned settings imaginable.

**Added #1:**

One more thing, RPi is being connected to the network by wifi (wlan0). It might or may not be important here.

**Added #2:**

Services actually work as expected when added to the `/etc/systemd/system/` and run "globally". But they refuse to start on boot when run as user, and that's what I'm after.

Output of `sudo loginctl show-user pi`:

```
UID=1000
GID=1000
Name=pi
Timestamp=Wed 2020-01-01 14:10:16 CET
TimestampMonotonic=8249110
RuntimePath=/run/user/1000
Service=user@1000.service
Slice=user-1000.slice
Display=c1
State=active
Sessions=c1
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=1577884640207702
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=421820778
Linger=yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind this is because this is a service that runs underneath the `pi` user.  As noted in the path of the service: `/home/pi/.config/systemd/`. This will only trigger the service up-on login.

In order for the a user service to work you need to enable linger for user `pi` by running the following command:

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger pi
```

For more information, see [man pages for loginctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/loginctl.1.html).

Also, note that `multi-user.target` is not a valid service for user service, you need to change `WantedBy` to `default.target` so that it becomes:

```
WantedBy=default.target
```

Now the service will boot on startup for the pi-user without login.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about that, but unfortunately enabling linger didn't change anything. I just tried with linger enabled multiple variations of service/unit configuration to the same effect.

Comment: I just checked that these services work correctly when added to the `/etc/systemd/system/`. They just don't work when run as user :/ .

Comment: Actually, thanks to your suggestion I figured out what is wrong, and explanation is here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2690#issuecomment-186973730 . So it looks like both things are required: enabled linger and `WantedBy=default.target` You can add it to your answer and I will gladly accept it, thanks! :)

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda I've updated the solution. Thanks for the clarification!