# systemd unit enabled but does not start on boot for user, only for root

Tags: systemd, systemctl, journalctl

I am lost, I don't know why this does not work for the **user** on reboot:

(not working means: if I start it manually using `systemctl --user start nostc` it works perfectly, no errors. In the logs there are no errors either). I just see that after a reboot, `Stopped` lines occur right before the reboot.

````
[Unit]
Description=nostc.service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/home/pascal/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/envs/feb2018/bin/nostalgia_chrome run_server
WorkingDirectory=/home/pascal/egoroot/nostalgia-dev/nostalgia_chrome
Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=on"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target```
````

It's really weird because:

`systemctl --user is-enabled nostc` shows enabled

On boot it shows:

```
● nostc.service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/pascal/.config/systemd/user/nostc.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: inactive (dead)
lines 1-3/3 (END)
```

But as **root** it does work (`systemctl is-enabled nostalgia_chrome` and runs):

```
[Unit]
Description=nostalgia_chrome service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=pascal
Group=users
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nostalgia_chrome run-server
Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=on"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Could multi-user be setup wrongly on arch+i3, or what could possibly be the issue?

Comment: What does `systemctl --user status nostc` show?

Comment: take a look a this answer, i'm sure it will help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559753/how-to-make-systemd-services-run-automatically-after-reboot

Comment: @D'ArcyNader That's it. So it should be `WantedBy=default.target`

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid for a user:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It should be most likely:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

There is no `multi-user.target` for per-user service management in systemd.

Read `man systemd.special`.

Comment: Do you know how to make it wanted by "something" for a user (such that it will always be started)?